Pydantic 2.6.4 validate_call vs isinstance
As the title suggests, I was testing validation performance of pydantic (vers=2.6.4) decorator @validate_call versus a simple isinstance() call.
Here the code
from pydantic import BaseModel, validate_call, ConfigDict

# Class with pydantic method validation
class User1(BaseModel):
    value:int

    @staticmethod
    @validate_call(config=ConfigDict(strict=True))
    def add(x:int, y:int) -> int:
        return x + y

# Class with "handmade" type validation
class User2(BaseModel):
    value:int

    @staticmethod
    def add(x:int, y:int) -> int:
        if not isinstance(x,int):
            raise TypeError('wrong x')
        if not isinstance(y,int):
            raise TypeError('wrong y')
        return x + y


user1 = User1(value=10)
user2 = User2(value=10)

Here the performance calling .add() method
%%timeit
user1.add(1,1)

554 ns ± 2.83 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
%%timeit
user2.add(1,1)

74.3 ns ± 4.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
Both classes are pydantic BaseModel classes. And in User1 I used config = ConfigDict...strict validation hoping for better performance (but using it or not makes no difference basically).
Shouldn't pydantic core be written in Rust? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?
I know that with validate_call you have acces to much more sophisticated validation and parsing methods but why it's so much slower than several if statements and isinstance() calls?

Maybe you are experiencing some overhead related problem? Half a microsecond isn't that much. Try to make twice as many variables (x, y, z, w). My guess is user1.add will not be twice slower.

That's for sure. Problem is, in the actual program I'm writing the function is  quite simple and fast but it's called countless times (it's part of the core of a flow simulation) so I would like to make it as fast as I can. I was wondering if there is a way to speed up pydantic validation (that is exactly what I was trying to achieve using config=ConfigDict...). Otherwise, maybe it's better validate everything during sim init phase and insert simply some assertion just to be sure (and remove them once the library has been tested sufficiently)

I must say I can't help you with that decision. I was asking myself if it is possible to turn off validations completely with some flag and found this thread: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/897#issuecomment-541872349 Maybe it will help you in some way.

I ended up relying on the attrs module. If you don't need creazy validations and parsing, it's a significant better choice. Simpler and much less overhead
